# Create a "to" column and "from" column from a single "length" column

Tags: excel

I have an Excel sheet with ~1800 rows and a few columns.

I have a length column,
[Length](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgJ6X.png)

That I would like to use to create 2 new columns (From and To),
[From-To](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPcqx.png)

I've seen posts somewhat similar to my question, but only with regards to date-time.
Thanks for any help, community...

Comment: What is the question? What have you tried? What does your sheet look like?

Comment: The question is "How to create a "to" column and "from" column from a single "length" column. I have tried researching the question. My sheet looks like the "Length" and "From-To" links posted in my question above.

Comment: So... not a programming question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible to just drag down a formula like:

[image]